# how can i use regexp in birt report and replace

Tags: birt

when i use birt, my data with sql query are contains many html tags,like

```
[quote][/quote]
 [img][/img]
```

,i prefer to replace it with regexp,but i can't successful,
i print

```
<VALUE-OF>row["content"].replace(/\[\/?[a-z]*\W*\w*]/gi, "")</VALUE-OF>
```

in 【edit text item】,
also i wrote 【data banding】 in expression with

```
dataSetRow["content"].replace(new RegExp("/[\[]\/?\W*]/g","ig"),"")
```

it failed,i have no idea
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the wrong method ,the right is replaceAll()